# Do I need a <p> inside my <div class="container"> if I'm not displaying text?

Tags: html

I don't think I do, but I put it in every time anyway. This is what it looks like. Can I take the p out?

```html
<div class="container" id="shortcuts">
<!-- All shortcut elements in div#shortcuts -->
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="int" id="bookmark" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" class="int" id="browser" />
        <!-- Shourtcut elements defined -->
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost all elements are optional. The markup you use is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you're right you don't need it at all. the

tag will just give the text a certain default styling.